# same alias different key OK between keystore and cacerts? Or, how to export/import key between keystore/cacerts?

Tags: java, certificate, keystore

On Linux Centos system with java 1.7, is it OK to use a key with alias `xyz123` in keystore.jks and a different key with the same alias in cacerts.jks? Or, will something break?

I deleted key with alias 'xyz123' (because it was 1024 bits) in keystore.jks file, then created a new key (for 2048 bits) with alias 'xyz123' for keystore using:

```
keytool -keysize 2048 -genkey -alias xyz123 -keyalg RSA 
-dname "CN=mydomain.com,OU=GF,O=MyCorp,
L=MyCity,ST=MyState,C=US" -validity 7300 -keypass 
mypwd -storepass mypwd -keystore keystore.jks
```

but now I noticed the alias `xyz123` (for old key) also exists in cacerts.jks. So, right now the same alias points to different keys between keystore and cacerts. I'm afraid if I repeat the code above but for cacerts, that although a new key goes into cacerts.jks, the same situation will still exist (e.g. the same alias points to different key between keystore and cacerts).

Is there a way to execute the above code but include both keystore and cacerts as line arguments somehow?

Or, perhaps what I need to know is how to generate a key as a separate file somehow, then how to import into each of keystore and cacerts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`-importkeystore`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/keytool.html#importKeyStoreCmd) option to import the newly generated key pair to the cacerts.jks keystore.

However, cacerts.jks should not contain private keys. It's a collection of "trust anchors"—certificates that can be used to verify other certificates. I would recommend [exporting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/keytool.html#exportCertCmd) only the new certificate from keystore.jks, and [importing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/keytool.html#importCertCmd) that to cacerts.jks, rather than the complete key pair.

Comment: Thanks @erickson, could you explain a little more about what you mean by `entries are enumerated and their alias is ignored`?

Comment: Nevermind about that; you changed your question so I changed my answer to fit.

Comment: To export/import could I use something like: `keytool -export –alias xyz123 -file xyz123.cer -keystore keystore.jks -storepass mypwd` then `keytool -import –alias xyz123 -file xyz123.cer -keystore cacerts.jks -storepass mypwd`?

Comment: @user46688 Yes, but `-export` and `-import` are deprecated names for the options that could be dropped someday. Use their replacements `-exportcert` and `-importcert`.

Comment: Thanks @erickson, How about `genkey`, should that be `genkeypair` or does that change functionality?

Comment: @user46688 Yes, use `-genkeypair`; it's the favored name for the same command.